# Pyplot scatter size and color not matching

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to create simple scatterplot from a pandas dataframe, plotting column1 against column2, and using column3 (of Boolean values) as both color and size.  However, despite the color and size arrays matching as expected, they apply to different points in the plot.

```
>>> colors = ['white' if not val else 'red' for val in df.column3.values]
>>> size = [5 if not val else 30 for val in df.column3.values]
>>> plt.scatter(df['column1'].values, df['column2'].values, c=colors, s=size)
>>> print zip(colors, size)
[('white', 5),
 ('white', 5),
 ('red', 30),
 ('red', 30),
 ('white', 5),
 ...]
```

[image]

Why is this happening?

E: To clarify, *every* element in the `color` and `size` arrays are paired correctly:

```
>>> for pair in zip(colors, size):
...     if (pair[0] == 'white' and pair[1] != 5) or (pair[0] == 'red' and pair[1] != 30):
...         print pair
[]
```

Comment: Did you mean to write "`in df.column**3**.values`" on the second line?

Comment: @DizietAsahi Yes, I did - thank you!

Comment: That *does not* verify that the pairs are correct if you have a large number of elements. You can't sanely visually inspect that. You'll need to do a filter with an assert. Something like `assert len(zip(colors, size)) == len([x for x in zip(colors, size) if (x[0] == 'white' and x[1] == 30) or (x[0] == 'red' and x[1] == 5)])`

Comment: Admittedly they should be the same given they are both generated the same way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved.  There were nulls in `column1` and `column2` that were not being plotted, but those nulls were not being skipped in the `color` and `size` arrays.  You need to ensure that you only create the `color` and `size` arrays using rows where neither of the other two columns are null, e.g.,

```
>>> tmpdf = df[~pd.isnull(df['column1']) & ~pd.isnull(df['column2]')]
>>> colors = ['white' if not val else 'red' for val in tmpdf.column3.values]
>>> size = [5 if not val else 30 for val in tmpdf.column3.values]
>>> plt.scatter(tmpdf['column1'].values, tmpdf['column2'].values, c=colors, s=size)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this happening?

Probably because you're not guaranteed (in general) to have two different dataframe columns to have Falsey data in the same spot.

```
>>> colors = ['white' if not val else 'red' for val in df.column3.values]
>>> size = [5 if not val else 30 for val in df.column2.values]
```

`colors` is created from `df.column3` and `size` is created from `df.column2` (I think maybe you *meant* to generate `size` from `df.column3`).

There's no guarantee that `'white'` will always pair with `5` and that `'red'` will always pair with `30` for the falsey data in the columns. If you want `'white'` to always pair with `5` and `'red'` to always pair with `30`, then best to generate your sizes from the colors:

```
>>> colors = ['white' if not val else 'red' for val in df.column3.values]
>>> size = [5 if val == 'white' else 30 for val in colors]
```

Then you can't get the mismatch.

HTH.

Comment: You are correct - I am generating `size` from column3 as well. I mistyped it when renaming columns to post publicly.

Comment: This makes sense, but as shown when `zip`ping the arrays together, in my `colors` and `size` arrays, "red" always pairs with 30 and "white" always pairs with 5, so it appears my arrays are correct.

Comment: Oh. And they're still mismatched?

Comment: @Tim Well, maybe for the first couple it *looks* correct. But you can't say it's correct for *every* element just by looking at the first couple of elements.

Comment: You're right - I'll edit my question to be clear that it's correct for every element in the arrays.